# Avoiding duplicate code in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using Stripe Checkout on my website and I use several buttons to open the checkout popup. I am now basically using the exact same code twice besides changing the id. Is there a way to combine this into one function?

```
document.getElementById('buyCourseButton').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // Open Checkout with further options:
  handler.open({
    name: 'Company name', // TODO
    description: 'Product description', // TODO
    currency: 'eur',
    amount: '{{ course_price }}'
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});

document.getElementById('buyCourseButton2').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  // Open Checkout with further options:
  handler.open({
    name: 'Company name', // TODO
    description: 'Product description', // TODO
    currency: 'eur',
    amount: '{{ course_price }}'
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: so make it a function and bind the function to the clicks `('click', yourFunction)`

Comment: I tried that, and called the function, but Stripe didn't accept that and showed me an error with `Invalid source object: must be a dictionary or a non-empty string.`

Comment: Show us what you did when you attempted to use a single function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jquery-multiple-selector](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```js
const handler = {
  open: a => console.log(a)
};
$('#buyCourseButton1,#buyCourseButton2').click(function(e) {
  handler.open({
    name: 'Company name', // TODO
    description: 'Product description', // TODO
    currency: 'eur',
    amount: '{{ course_price }}'
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="buyCourseButton1">Button one</button>
<button id="buyCourseButton2">Button two</button>
```

Comment: Ironically it even works that way when I give every button the same id. But as soon I remove ,#buyCourseButton2 it doesn't work anymore. Do you see any logic in this behaviour?

Comment: In a dom id must be unique, having duplicate id is surely anti pattern and not acceptable

Answer (score 0):

Give the buttons a class and use make an array from `getElementsByClassName`:

```js
const handler = {
  open: a => console.log(a)
};

Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('buyCourseButton')).forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // Open Checkout with further options:
    handler.open({
      name: 'Company name', // TODO
      description: 'Product description', // TODO
      currency: 'eur',
      amount: '{{ course_price }}'
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });

});
```

```html
<button class="buyCourseButton">Button one</button>
<button class="buyCourseButton">Button two</button>
```

Comment: Class didn't work, unfortunately, but the jquery-multiple-selector solved it.

Comment: Class won't work unless you give the buttons a class of course

Comment: I changed them to class when trying it. But it seems Stripe doesn't accept this.